# Use sum case sql in Crystal command to show sales in this year and last year?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, command, multiple-columns

I am using the sql code below in the Crystal "Command" to display current years sales units and dollars (all closed sales versus sales closed using a discount).  I need to add the last years unit sales qty. Does anyone have any idea the nest way to do this? Thanks to anyone who has any ideas.

Code:

```
SELECT

convert(char(4),datepart(yy,m.close_dt)) +
       right('00' +   convert(varchar,datepart(m,m.close_dt)),2) AS SortMonth,

replace(right(convert(varchar(11), m.close_dt, 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS DisplayMonth,
sum(case when lt.um_ch177= 'BAWRM' then 1 else 0 end) as Close_Units_Disc ,
sum(case when lt.um_ch177= 'BAWRM' then m.tot_ln_amt else 0 end) as Close_Dollars_Disc,

sum(case when m.close_dt >= '{?Date1}'
    and m.close_dt <= '{?Date2}' then 1 else 0 end) as Close_Units_All,
sum(case when m.close_dt >= '{?Date1}'
    and m.close_dt <= '{?Date2}' then tot_ln_amt else 0 end) as Close_Dollars_All

FROM
pro2sql.lt_master m WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN pro2sql.ltuch_master lt WITH (NOLOCK) ON m.lt_acnt=lt.lt_acnt

WHERE
m.stage = 60
and m.loan_purpose <> 7 
and m.app_number <> 0
and m.brch_entry {?BranchList}



and m.close_dt >= '{?Date1}'
and m.close_dt <'{?Date2}'

Group by

convert(char(4),datepart(yy,m.close_dt)) + right('00' +   convert(varchar,datepart(m,m.close_dt)),2) 
,replace(right(convert(varchar(11), m.close_dt, 106), 8), ' ', '-')
```

I can't upload a pic - not sure if this is going to be a jumble but here is the output - the last two columns are what I need to add:

```
DisplayMonth  Close_Units_Disc  Close_Dollars_Disc  Close_Units_All  Close_Dollars_All  %Units  %Dollars  DisplayMonth  LY CloseUnits All
Feb-2014            115             $48,919,800        190         $83,942,650         61%       58%     Feb-2013   
Mar-2014            202             $91,077,780        238         $109,300,903    85%       83%     Mar-2013   
Apr-2014            219             $89,157,481        238         $95,892,509         92%       93%     Apr-2013
```

Comment: Are {?Date1} or {?Date1} always Current year dates? And what is your database?

Comment: Our fiscal year is Nov 1 - Oct 31 - so Date 1 = 11/01/2013 and date 2 will actually be the last day of each month since it's a monthly report. Data is pulling from our enterprise system. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Enterprise system"  is not an adequate answer. What type of database is this? Oracle? Microsoft (and which version if its MSS)? Something else?

That may influence what solutions are possible, or at least the syntax

You have at least two options off the top of my head though:

**One:**

- Expand the date range to pull in the previous year's data;
- modify all of your `sum case` statements to include the current year only.
- add an additional `sum case` with appropriate date range conditions for the previous year's units.

**Two:**

- duplicate your query as a subquery for the previous year and join to it

e.g:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
replace(right(convert(varchar(11), m.close_dt, 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS DisplayMonth,
SELECT sum(case when lt.um_ch177= 'BAWRM' then 1 else 0 end) as Close_Units_Disc 
FROM pro2sql.lt_master m WITH (NOLOCK)

LEFT OUTER JOIN pro2sql.ltuch_master lt WITH (NOLOCK) ON m.lt_acnt=lt.lt_acnt

WHERE m.stage = 60 and m.loan_purpose <> 7 and m.app_number <> 0
      and m.brch_entry {?BranchList}
      and m.close_dt >= '{?Date3}'   --//#last year's start date
      and m.close_dt <'{?Date4}'`    --//#last year's end date

Group by
  convert(char(4),datepart(yy,m.close_dt)) + 
          right('00' + convert(varchar,datepart(m,m.close_dt)),2),
  replace(right(convert(varchar(11), m.close_dt, 106), 8), ' ', '-') 
) as lastYear
on replace(right(convert(varchar(11), m.close_dt, 106), 8), ' ', '-') = lastYear.DisplayMonth
```

If you go with one of these, you may want to consult with a DBA at your company to see which would be more efficient... I don't know if running a query with a larger result is more intensive than running nearly identical queries twice, and that too may change form one architecture to another (or even just with different environment variables/parameters configured on the server)